# Videos are directly streaming onto my default player. Want to open in Opera so I can download it

Tags: default-applications, opera-browser, video-streaming

I have been using Android for the last week.

I have Opera for browsing. I  download videos from a website directly thru Opera. While downloading it asks me whether to open the video in Opera or default video player of my mobile.

Accidentally I once clicked on the "make it default" option and it was directly streamed to the video player. After this it never open in my Opera to download.

Because of this I can't download videos into my mobile. If I try to search the name of the video player I cant find it. And please help to restore as it was before.

Answer (score 2):

You *shouldn't* need to uninstall anything. You just need to clear the default.

Go into your settings and the app manager. Find the default video player. (You'll probably have to change your view from "Downloaded" to "All" in order to find it. I expect it's called "Video" or similar.) In the settings for the app should be a button labeled "Clear defaults". Tap that and remove the existing default settings for the app.

Now when you go back into Opera and click a link it should prompt you again. Be careful about that "make it the default" button.

Answer (score 1):

If all the other answers look too complicated, or are not suiting you for other reasons: There are apps available helping you to [Manage Default Apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_5). Two examples of that are [Clear Defaults](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.droidzeal.cleardefaults) and [Default App Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.appiator.defaultappmanager):

[image: Clear Defaults] [image: Default App Manager]

The former simply lets you *clear* the default for an action type, while the letter also lets you chose which app should be the default, which might come in handy – though it's not strictly required, as Android would ask you the next time anyway if there is no default set.

Answer (score 0):

Trying uninstalling the Opera browser:

```
 Settings > Applications > Manage applications
```

and then reinstalling it.

Alternatively download a new web browser (e.g., [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser)) and once that is installed, launch your video and it should give you the option of selecting Opera as your default.

Comment: No need to uninstall -- any update (of the default app) will do, as will the installation of any other app handling that special content-type (Mime), which must not be a web browser (see [Al's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/35652/16575): A video player app is much more likely to solve the issue).

Comment: @Izzy - Thx, I've already read his answer

Answer (score -2):

Just install another Video Player app.

As this adds a new possible choice, it will reset the "default" setting as a side-effect – and save you the work of finding the app currently set as default.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/118780)

Comment: @AndrewT. actually, it does. It just misses the background of why it would work: it would reset the "default action" as a side-effect of adding a "new option". And it would save you the hassle of finding out which app currently bears the default ;)